# token transfer fails

Tags: solidity, tokens, address.transfer

I copied the GNT, ZIL, GTO token code from mainnet and deployed each token to rinkeby.

- `GNT token contract : 0x861783a4B946026e3180FCA173261d937aa2fabF`
- `ZIL token contract : 0x1dD42376F6902F812E03C3861Da3c8654462c267`
- `GTO token contract : 0x8970fd3E01504D5b83d48faFbad92547AE9B6630`

`TestContract1` and `TestContract2` and `TestContract3` were distributed using Remix as shown below.

After depositing a token in each contract, I called the `transfer()` function

But,

- `TestContract1 : transaction success`
- `TestContract2 : transaction fail`
- `TestContract3 : transaction fail`

`TestContract2` and `TestContract3` had an error (`Gas estimation failed`) in Remix, but it did send transaction.

I'm so frustrated because I can not figure out the cause of the failure, so I want to get expert advice.

---

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract Token {
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract TestContract1 {

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public returns (bool success) {
    // GNT token contract 
        address tokenContract = 0x861783a4B946026e3180FCA173261d937aa2fabF;

        Token _tokenSomething = Token(tokenContract);

        _tokenSomething.transfer(_to, _amount);

        return true;
    }
}

contract TestContract2 {

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public returns (bool success) {
    // ZIL token contract 
        address tokenContract = 0x1dD42376F6902F812E03C3861Da3c8654462c267

        Token _tokenSomething = Token(tokenContract);

        _tokenSomething.transfer(_to, _amount);

        return true;
    }
}

contract TestContract3 {

    function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public returns (bool success) {
    // GTO token contract 
        address tokenContract = 0x8970fd3E01504D5b83d48faFbad92547AE9B6630

        Token _tokenSomething = Token(tokenContract);

        _tokenSomething.transfer(_to, _amount);

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

TestContract1 transaction result :
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xdef60351224e0b3ca298888878aefc975787a67cfea3d5428f94ba74759205df

TestContract2 transaction result :
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9975ab7bb92447e865e0e34bbc670e3f2a34e8d31c40ecdac35185408abe2bd0

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem

Comment: No, not yet. I have no idea yet. :(

Comment: Is that the full code? It does not implement the RC20 standard.

Comment: I found my mistake. Token contract deployment was incorrect. It works fine.